# Fix WebApplicationBuilder.Services ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm trying to create a custom registration web app using AspNetCore.Identity and .NET 7.

This is my code in the `program.cs` file:

```
using AspNetIdentity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>();
```

but the last line throws this error:

> The property 'WebApplicationBuilder.Services' cannot be used with type arguments

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rely on Intellisense to discover what's wrong.  Basically, `Services` is a property, not a method.  Properties do not receive generic arguments.  you want  `Services.AddXXX`, where `XXX` is `Singleton`, `Scopped` or `Transient`.

Comment: you're right, It was supposed to be Services.AddIdentity